# display birthday on current date from a category in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display posts from a category 'Birthday' from current date.

How I can show all post from a day and month. But it should not require any Year parameter.

I have tried it with

```
   <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
```

but it take year also.

Please help me, i want to display today's birthday

Answer (score 1):

Argument must be an array

```
 <?php wp_get_archives(array('type'=>'monthly')); ?>
```

Comment: What will be the url for archive monthly.